# best way to support several paths when implementing http server in java

Tags: java, rest, http

I'm new to http and a bit confused regarding the various options to establish rest service.(Simple, HTTP Library by oracle, Jersey, Restlet...)

my need is to create a server which can receive and respond to http requests. 
I used this link: [Create Very Simple Jersey REST Service and Send JSON Data From Java Client](http://crunchify.com/create-very-simple-jersey-rest-service-and-send-json-data-from-java-client/)

it works like a charm, however I have several paths, which means I will need @Post method for each url.(each url represents an action, delete/create/get_info etc...)

I read something about Restlet, which is able to create http server with benefits upon its competitors. would someone elaborate a bit more when I will use Restlet (in a context of http server, not creating/using api.)

is jersey with several @post methods good solution to send and receive JSON messages over http?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted looks like a really good example and tutorial. Based on what you have described and the fact you got it partially working, adding additional methods seems like the best approach for supporting multiple paths.

n.b. I wouldn't call this method overloading since the java method names should be different.

Comment: sounds good, I was not sure if its a best practice due to the various solutions are offered.